# Numbering in subequation and align environments

Tags: align, subequations

I use the `subequations` and `align` environments as follows:

```
 \begin{subequations}
 \begin{align}
   \sum_{a \in \delta^+_G(v)} f^k_a -  \sum_{a \in \delta^-_G(v)} f^k_a  &= d^k_v, & \forall v \in V, k \in K \\ 
    \sum_{k \in K} f^k_a  &\le \sum_{m \in M}c^m x^m_a, & \forall a \in A   & \quad \texttt{Directed}\\
    \max \left\{\sum_{k \in K} \{f^k_{e+},f^k_{e-}\}  \right\}&\le \sum_{m \in M}c^m x^m_a, & \forall e \in E   & \quad \texttt{Bidirected}\\
    \sum_{k \in K} (f^k_{e+}+f^k_{e-})&\le \sum_{m \in M}c^m x^m_e, & \forall e \in E   & \quad \texttt{Undirected}
 \end{align}
 \end{subequations}
```

which shows the equations numbered as
1.a
1.b
1.c
1.d

However, I'd like the numbering to be displayed as
1
2.a
2.b
2.c

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a Minimal Working Example, instead of a code snippet.

Answer (score 5):

I would like to suggest that you (a) embed all four statements in a `gather` environment and (b) embed the *three inequalities* in combined `subequations` and `alignat` environments. I would also recommend using `\smashoperator` directives in order to typeset the summation expressions in the first row more compactly.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for \smashoperator macro

\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
   \smashoperator{\sum_{a \in \delta^+_G(v)}} f^k_a -  
   \smashoperator{\sum_{a \in \delta^-_G(v)}} f^k_a  = 
   d^k_v, \quad \forall v \in V,\ k \in K
\\[\jot]
\begin{subequations}
\begin{alignat}{3}
  \sum_{k \in K} f^k_a  
  &\le \sum_{m \in M}c^m x^m_a, 
  &\qquad& \forall a \in A   
  & \quad& \texttt{Directed} \\
  \max \biggl\{\sum_{k \in K} \{f^k_{e+},f^k_{e-}\}  \biggr\}
  &\le \sum_{m \in M}c^m x^m_a, 
  && \forall e \in E   
  && \texttt{Bidirected} \\
  \sum_{k \in K} (f^k_{e+}+f^k_{e-})
  &\le \sum_{m \in M}c^m x^m_e, 
  && \forall e \in E   
  &&  \texttt{Undirected}
\end{alignat}
\end{subequations}
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

Comment: + Very good suggestion to use smash for the summation symbol. Personally I would use `\tag` for sub equations. Nice and simple.

Answer (score 4):

Mico just posted his answer as I was writing this, and you should consider that, but to directly answer the question with `align` I'd probably not use `subequations` and simply tag the later equations so

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

 \begin{align}
   \sum_{a \in \delta^+_G(v)} f^k_a -  \sum_{a \in \delta^-_G(v)} f^k_a  &= d^k_v, & \forall v \in V, k \in K \\ 
    \sum_{k \in K} f^k_a  &\le \sum_{m \in M}c^m x^m_a, & \forall a \in A   & \quad \texttt{Directed} \refstepcounter{equation}\tag{\theequation a}\\
    \max \left\{\sum_{k \in K} \{f^k_{e+},f^k_{e-}\}  \right\}&\le \sum_{m \in M}c^m x^m_a, & \forall e \in E   & \quad \texttt{Bidirected} \tag{\theequation b}\\
    \sum_{k \in K} (f^k_{e+}+f^k_{e-})&\le \sum_{m \in M}c^m x^m_e, & \forall e \in E   & \quad \texttt{Undirected}  \tag{\theequation c}
 \end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The simpler the better, always!

Answer (score 4):

You can define a new `specialsubequations` environment in which the first item is treated specially with the help of `\specialequation`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{hyperref} % not mandatory

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text, don't load it in your document

\makeatletter
\newcounter{specialsubequations}
\newenvironment{specialsubequations}
 {%
  \stepcounter{specialsubequations}%
  \stepcounter{equation}%
  \let\@currentlabel\theequation
  \label{@@@fake\thespecialsubequations @@@}%
  \subequations
 }
 {\endsubequations}
\@ifpackageloaded{hyperref}{%
  \newcommand{\specialequation}{\tag{\ref*{@@@fake\thespecialsubequations @@@}}}%
}{%
  \newcommand{\specialequation}{\tag{\ref{@@@fake\thespecialsubequations @@@}}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-3]
\begin{specialsubequations}
\begin{align}
  \sum_{a \in \delta^+_G(v)} f^k_a -  \sum_{a \in \delta^-_G(v)} f^k_a
  &= d^k_v, & \forall v \in V, k \in K \specialequation\label{1}
  \\ 
  \sum_{k \in K} f^k_a  &\le \sum_{m \in M}c^m x^m_a, 
  & \forall a \in A   & \quad \texttt{Directed}
  \\
  \max \left\{\sum_{k \in K} \{f^k_{e+},f^k_{e-}\}  \right\}
  &\le \sum_{m \in M}c^m x^m_a, & \forall e \in E   & \quad \texttt{Bidirected}
  \\
  \sum_{k \in K} (f^k_{e+}+f^k_{e-})&\le \sum_{m \in M}c^m x^m_e,
  & \forall e \in E   & \quad \texttt{Undirected}
\end{align}
\end{specialsubequations}
\lipsum[2][1-3]

\end{document}
```

You can add a `\label` to the special equation; links will work when `hyperref` is loaded.

[image]

However I'd recommend not changing the number.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{hyperref} % not mandatory; use `\ref*` if hyperref is loaded

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-3]
\begin{subequations}\label{main}
\begin{align}
  \sum_{a \in \delta^+_G(v)} f^k_a -  \sum_{a \in \delta^-_G(v)} f^k_a
  &= d^k_v, & \forall v \in V, k \in K \tag{\ref{main}}
  \\ 
  \sum_{k \in K} f^k_a  &\le \sum_{m \in M}c^m x^m_a, 
  & \forall a \in A   & \quad \texttt{Directed}
  \\
  \max \left\{\sum_{k \in K} \{f^k_{e+},f^k_{e-}\}  \right\}
  &\le \sum_{m \in M}c^m x^m_a, & \forall e \in E   & \quad \texttt{Bidirected}
  \\
  \sum_{k \in K} (f^k_{e+}+f^k_{e-})&\le \sum_{m \in M}c^m x^m_e,
  & \forall e \in E   & \quad \texttt{Undirected}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
\lipsum[2][1-3]

\end{document}
```

[image]